# Keylistener in Javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard, key, keylistener

I'm looking for a `KeyListener` for a game I'm developing in JavaScript. I have no idea how this would work in real code but it would be something like this:

```
if(keyPress == upKey)
{
    playerSpriteX += 10;
}
else if(keyPress == downKey)
{
    playerSpriteY -= 10;
}
```

etc...

I searched it up, and Google came up with things that involved AJAX which I don't understand yet. Is there a built in function in JavaScript that does this?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Here's an update for modern browsers in 2019

```js
let playerSpriteX = 0;

document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.code === "ArrowUp")        playerSpriteX += 10
  else if (e.code === "ArrowDown") playerSpriteX -= 10

  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'playerSpriteX = ' + playerSpriteX;
});
```

```html
Click on this window to focus it, and hit keys up and down
<br><br><br>
<div id="test">playerSpriteX = 0</div>
```

---

Original answer from 2013

```
window.onkeyup = function(e) {
   var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

   if (key == 38) {
       playerSpriteX += 10;
   }else if (key == 40) {
       playerSpriteX -= 10;
   }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ks6ht/1/)

Comment: `keyCode` is deprecated, consider using `code` instead  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Answer (score 17):

The code is

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    alert(event.keyCode);
} );
```

This return the ascii code of the key. If you need the key representation, use event.key (This will return 'a', 'o', 'Alt'...)

Comment: It's [`keyCode`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp), not `keycode`

Answer (score 9):

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tgxBB/)

If you don't want the event to be continuous (if you want the user to have to release the key each time), change `onkeydown` to `onkeyup`

```
window.onkeydown = function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (code === 38) { //up key
        alert('up');
    } else if (code === 40) { //down key
        alert('down');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you check the small [Mousetrap](https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap) library?

Mousetrap is a simple library for handling keyboard shortcuts in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more readable comparing is done by casting `event.key` to upper case (I used onkeyup - needed the event to fire once upon each key tap):

```
window.onkeyup = function(event) {
    let key = event.key.toUpperCase();
    if ( key == 'W' ) {
        // 'W' key is pressed
    } else if ( key == 'D' ) {
        // 'D' key is pressed
    }
}
```

Each key has it's own code, get it out by outputting value of "key" variable (eg for arrow up key it will be 'ARROWUP' - (casted to uppercase))