# Invert number stepper

Tags: html, input

Is there any way to invert the HTML5 number stepper so that pressing down makes the number largers and vice versa?

**To address any 'Why?' comments:**
Batting order in sport, such as cricket or baseball. If you move *down* the order your batting position gets larger.

Comment: Attach an event listener that changes the `.val()` of the input as a result of a keycode and then increment it based on the element's step.

Comment: I think this would still be counter-intuitive to users, but if you really want to, use a JavaScript key event listener and `preventDefault`.

Comment: @EricHotinger I have a very shallow understanding of javascript so you're going to have to explain in more detail.

Comment: @Dave Seeing as I'll be the only one using it, it will not be *counter-intuitive*. And please explain further

Comment: @user1672694 - I'm going to sleep soon, so I won't answer the question in full.  If there isn't an answer in the morning, I'll post one.

Comment: @EricHotinger thats fine, I can wait. Thank you

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17015116/1180785 and the `preventDefault` I mentioned before, should be enough to get you started.

Comment: @Dave I can't get it working with the number stepper, here's a fiddle if you can help figure it out: http://jsfiddle.net/Syy6R/

Comment: ah, you seem to be talking about the buttons (I assumed the arrow keys; your example works fine with the arrow keys on the keyboard). Try listening for the `change` event and check how the value changes. I see you are already using jQuery, that makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick method which uses jQuery (since your sample used it):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var step=$('#batpos1');
    var o=+step.val();
    step.change(function(){
        var n=+step.val();
        if(n===o+1){
            --o;
        }else if(n===o-1){
            ++o;
        }else{
            o=n;
        }
        step.val(o);
    });
});
```

Note that it will also apply to keyboard arrow presses, but *will also apply when data is typed manually*. Right now I'm not sure how to avoid that, but I will update if I find a solution. A crude option would be to listen for clicks and only apply this if it changes within ±0.05 seconds of a click, or something like that.

Comment: -*will also apply when data is typed manually* What do you mean?

Comment: type in 1 and press enter. it will change to -1

Comment: Ok. Seems to only be for 1 and -1 though.

Comment: Any number which is 1 greater or lower than the current value will be swapped. That's how the logic I wrote works (if new value = old value + 1, set to old value - 1, etc.)