# Simultaneous function call in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

here is the code:

```
var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');
var chop1   = new Image();
chop1.src = "img/chopper.png";
var blt = new Image();
blt.src = "img/bullet.png"
var chopperX = 0;
var chopperY = 0;
var ascent = 2;
var limit = 500;
var start = null;
var bltX = 135;

function fire()
{
 bltX +=ascent;
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(blt,bltX,20 , 
chop1.width, chop1.height);
requestAnimationFrame(fire);


}


function up(){
    chopperY-=ascent;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(chop1,0,chopperY , 
              chop1.width, chop1.height);

    requestAnimationFrame(up);

if(chopperY == 20){
    setInterval(fire,1000)



}
if(chopperY == 0){

   fly();
}
 }

function fly() {
chopperY+=ascent;
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(chop1,0,chopperY , 
              chop1.width, chop1.height);
if (chopperY < limit) {
    requestAnimationFrame(fly);
}
if(chopperY==limit){

   up();
}
fly();
```

As per the condition(chopperY == 20),"fire" method is excute.But i want to call "fire" and "fly" function simultaneously at this particular condition. Is there any way to do this? In this code when "fire" method excute then "fly" method stop automatically.Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by simultaneous? You can only call functions one after another, and decide which is first...

Comment: @Carlos-first fire then fly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are making a game. You should use event listeners. See [some examples here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) or [keyboard examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015019/keylistener-in-javascript). This would allow you to connect keyboard actions to code and they should run at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but if your goal is, to pass two functions to `setInterval`, than you can achieve this by wrapping them up in an anonymous function:

```
if(chopperY == 20){
    setInterval(function () {
        fire();
        fly();
    },1000)
}
```

This will call both functions every second. However, the `fire` function will get executed first.