# Adding keypress Events that use an existing function

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events

I have used a function which is activated on click events. I want to do the same using keypress events.

```
function addToText(target) {

  var exp = target.target;
  //alert(exp.value);
  if (newExp) {

    //clearText();
    document.getElementById("expression").value = exp.value;
    newExp=false;

  } 

  else
    document.getElementById("expression").value = document.getElementById("expression").value + exp.value;

}
```

This is the function used. How do I modify it to use for keypress events also. Currently, it does not work initially(for keypress events). But after clicking once, then any keypress returns the same number that was previously clicked.

Full code here:http://codepen.io/jpninanjohn/pen/JXVpYb?editors=1010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's is your final solution, I test if charcode is between 48 and 57, what it means, numbers between 0 and 9.

```
   document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
      if (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57)
        document.getElementById("expression").value+= String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    });
```

Comment: Okay. This works but only after i click inside the calculator somewhere.

Comment: Are you sure? I have tested your edited codepen and it works even if I click outside the calculator and start typing.

Comment: Yes i checked again and it works for an outside click as well. But why the initial Click???

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function-

```
window.onkeyup = function(e) {
   var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
 document.getElementById("expression").value += key-48; //for getting the number

  alert(key);
   if (key == 38) {
      //whatever
   }else if (key == 40) {
      // whatever
   }
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015019/keylistener-in-javascript)

And you need to add + to the =

```
document.getElementById("expression").value+=
```

instead of -

```
document.getElementById("expression").value=
```

Comment: var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;   What does this line do??

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a different function for keyPress event, because the keypress event get the value of pressed key differently, not target.target

```
function addToTextKeypress(event) {

  var exp = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  //alert(exp);
  if (newExp) {

    //clearText();
    document.getElementById("expression").value = exp;
    newExp=false;

  } 

  else
    document.getElementById("expression").value = document.getElementById("expression").value + exp;

}
```

Later you need to remove exp.value since it has the direct value