# Reactjs - get input from hardware other than keyboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am writing a ReactJS application and I need to be able to read barcodes with a dedicated barcode scanner.

I am completely lost on this one. I found a few components on github, but I kind of fail at figuring out how to get the input from the scanner. I do know its output is only a string, but I have to be able to scan a product at any time without focusing on a `textfield` or other components.

**Workflow:**

scan product -> **get scanned value** -> call rest service

The scanner is just a simple USB device.

Best thing would be to maybe `dispatch` an `action` on scan event.

I am very thankful for even slight ideas or tips!

**EDIT:** I am also using **Redux**

Comment: Without knowing how this device is accessible from a browser environment, this isn't really related to react or redux at all. More of a hardware interface question. Does the device have a driver for your OS? Is there even a UI or could you do this with Node if it has to be JS?

Comment: The scanner reads a barcode on button press. If I do this with notepad opened, it pastes the readout as if I did `CTRL+V`. So I guess there has to be a keyboard event somewhere. In that case, I think it is related to react. It doesn't have a driver/UI, it just inserts whatever it reads into a text field. I actually thought about doing a `focus` on a text field if I press a button and just read it that way. Although it would be quite cool to just read barcodes without any other action.

Comment: Hm, if this thing just uses the OS's copy-paste command you just have to make sure the right text input (or area) is focused and then use React's `onChange` handler on the input to do something with the value. You would call `this.props.asyncReduxAction(changeEvent.target.value)` in this handler, and probably disable the input while the request is in progress or something.

Comment: Will look into that in a second. I just tried using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015019/keylistener-in-javascript) response and I do get almost every digit if I decode the numbers according to [this](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm) list, except the very first ones. It might read too slowly. [Here's](https://imgur.com/a/PR8uP) the code AFTER being decoded. The original barcode consists of the numbers `9009700306215`

Comment: if you have to wait for multiple copy-paste events until the barcode is complete, I'd try to debug this with `<input type="text" onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)} />`. As long as the device doesn't give you any keycodes that take focus (tab, enter, escape) off the input, it should work. You can then check for length === 13 for example to detect that it's complete and the api call can start.

Comment: Check [this](https://pastebin.com/dqgMf81p) out. It actually works. `a` is a `var` outside the function. This is the [log](https://imgur.com/a/xy075).
Going to look into your suggestions, it may be cleaner than this. EDIT: link works now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this working by creating an `onkeypress` event handler on `window`. There, I first parsed the `keycode` with `String.fromCharCode(...)` and then just appended it to my `barcode` field.

The problem here was, that there are barcodes with different lengths. In my case I had to be able to handle 13 and 8 sized barcodes, which was a bit difficult, since the reader never returned some kind of `eof` symbol.

I configured the reader to return key `13` after reading, which coresponds to `ENTER`. Here's a whole [list](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) with key codes btw.

After reading `13` the whole barcode was already scanned.

Then, I added my event `handler` method to `componentDidMount()` and dispatched the returned `barcode` in `mapDispatchToProps` and saved the returned element (backend) in my store.

Here's the code:

```
  scan = scannedBarcode => {
    console.log("SCANNED")
    this.props.getProductByBarcode(scannedBarcode);
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    // Setup Key Listener for the barcode scanner

    let self = this;

    window.onkeypress = function(e) {
      let barcode = "";
      let code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
      barcode=barcode+String.fromCharCode(code);
      scannedBarcode += barcode;

      if (code === ENTER_KEY) {
        console.log("DISPATCHING: " + scannedBarcode);
        self.scan(scannedBarcode);
        scannedBarcode = '';
      }
    }
  }
```

And here's `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return { 
    getProductByBarcode: barcode => {
      dispatch(getProductByBarcode(barcode)) ... }
```