# How to get user keyboard input asynchronously in C# / asp.Net / Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I work on a simple game clone of pacman. The only thing i have a problem with is how to get input from the user via keyboard to change the direction of the pacman (left, right, up, down).

Currently, i am using html buttons to redirect the window to the action which changes the variable in a "core" class. It works but not at all times. Pacman moves via javascript timeout function, where each 250 miliseconds, pacman moves in a direction which is stored in mentioned variable. It has sometimes a problem to capture the button click. (i guess because of the js timeout) Any help appriciated!

Mentioned JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     setTimeout(function () {
                     window.location.href = '/Home/Move';
                }, 250);
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: I think your problem doesn't have anything about c# or razor pages, it's all about javascript

Comment: what you need is a keylisterner in js. this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015019/keylistener-in-javascript

but I don't think this will solve your problem. you're reloading the page every 250 ms. that means 4 reloads per second. during the reloading neither a click on a button nor  pressing a key will work - or is delayed. this gonna get worse once your game is not on the localhost anymore because reloads will take more time.

finnaly I don't see any asynchronous code. I think you should work with ajax or write the logic of the game completely in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        // up arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        // down arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
       // left arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
       // right arrow
    }
}
```